# how subuid works in context of docker?

Tags: docker

Below is the content of /etc/subuid on my system.

**On host**

```
#cat /etc/subuid
incgnito:100000:65536

$ id -u
1000
```

1000 is UID of user **incgnito**

Now as per above content, UID 0 on container should be mapped to UID 100000 on system, but after logging to container , I found UID 0 inside container is mapped to UID 1000 on my system.

**On Container**

```
# cat /proc/1/uid_map 
         0       1000          1
         1     100000      65536
```

Can anyone help me to understand this concept?